# SQL Azure stored procedure timeout issue

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a stored procedure that when is executed directly against the database takes 1 second to run. It returns 46 rows of data.

The stored procedure is executed in code for my web site and returns data to create a report.

This works exactly as expected locally, takes a very short time (1/2 seconds) to load the report. When the web site is first deployed the report works as expected.

However, after a period of time (roughly half an hour) the report does not load because the stored procedure is timing out.

To get around this, if I drop and create the procedure it will start working again, but this is obviously not a solution to my problem.

The stored procedure is called in code like this:

```
DataSet content = new DataSet();

Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
DbCommand cmdSearchQuestionLibrary = db.GetStoredProcCommand("SP_NAME");

db.AddInParameter(cmdSearchQuestionLibrary, "@Param1", DbType.Int64, Id);
db.AddInParameter(cmdSearchQuestionLibrary, "@StartDate", DbType.DateTime, dtStartDate);
db.AddInParameter(cmdSearchQuestionLibrary, "@EndDate", DbType.DateTime, dtEndDate);
content = db.ExecuteDataSet(cmdSearchQuestionLibrary);
```

Has anyone experienced this before? Or know what could be causing the issue?

Comment: Try recompiling the SP on run. This may narrow down the issue. [See here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/02/20/sql-server-recompile-stored-procedure-at-run-time/)

Answer (score 2):

2 things you may try
1. UPDATE STATISTICS (Transact-SQL) : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187348.aspx

2. sp_recompile (Transact-SQL) : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181647.aspx

Comment: Number 2 solved the problem for me! Thanks a million!

Comment: @DavedeJong What is it that you changed? C# code or SP query?

Comment: @Rafael, suggestion 2 of Kaushik Ghosh fixed it for me, so I recompiled the stored procedure. But this only fixed it for a day so there must be something wrong with my SP. I now abandoned the SP altogether and implemented the query in linq.

Comment: @DavedeJong Thanks, I was curious but I too switched to LinQ which works nice with EF migration

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the best way to figure out what is going wrong is to take a look at what is happening in the database at the time.  One common reason might be based on blocking queries.

If it helps, our Cotega database monitoring service provides a free capability to [analyze a SQL Azure database](http://cotega.com/docs/analyze_database) which executes most of the common queries used to find issues such as this.  This includes blocking queries which might provide some additional insight.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the stored procedure used to work for years and then one day it started to time out.
I re-compile the stored procedure and publish the web app again. And then the timeout problem doesn't show up again.